# ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLSession' from 'requests_html'

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

When I tried to use the new module *requests_html* using the example of its website,I found the console displays information in the title.

- I have successfully installed *requests_html* using `pip install requests_html`
- I have updated the python to python3.7 (64-bit)

The messages of console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/owlish/PycharmProjects/python34/requests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
  File "C:\Users\owlish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 10, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\owlish\PycharmProjects\python34\requests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLSession' from 'requests_html' (C:\Users\owlish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py)
```

code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://python.org/')
```

I expect it to work without an error,like the examples https://html.python-requests.org/.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no file.py in the current directory named 'HTMLSession.py'? There is a probability that another file is overshadowing the original file that you're trying to import from.

Comment: @AhmedHawary OK,you are right,I created a file named 'requests.py' which has a same name with the keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With AhmedHawary's help,I found the reason for the error:I had a file named *requests.py* , which confilcted with the *keywords* . It worked fine after I renamed the file name.

Comment: Worked for me, too.  This was so unexpected, but makes sense now (even if I hate it).

Comment: Thanks, also I had an error (`ImportError: cannot import name 'HTML' from partially initialized module 'requests_html' (most likely due to a circular import)`) when my script name was `parse.py`

Comment: I got `ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncHTMLSession' from partially initialized module 'requests_html'` whn my script was named `signal.py`